# How can I build a recommender system that accepts data of varying granularity?

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

I'm tasked with building a recommender system that can make recommendations based on input data **of varying levels of granularity**. To explain what I mean, let's use a running example of a *Movie Title Recommender*.

#### Desired interface

Suppose I have a recommender system model, `R`, which is already defined and trained.

I want to be able to provide a single movie title, and get a ranked list of movie titles the models deems to be similar:

```
query = {'movie':'Shrek'} # input query

R(query) = ['A Bugs Life', 'Toy Story', 'Shrek 2'...] # ranked list of similar movies
```

I would also like to be able to optionally incorporate additional information, beyond just the movie title, which would somehow *re-weight* the recommendation scores.

For example, suppose I could optionally incorporate the gender of a user.

```
query = {'movie':'Shrek',
         'user_gender' : 'female'}  # query updated to specify user gender

# recommendation system takes gender into account, yielding different ordering in result
R(query) = ['Shrek 2', 'Finding Nemo', 'Toy Story', ...]
```

#### Considerations

The specific method doesn't matter to me - whether it be a collaborative filtering, matrix factorization or some other approach. What I'm most interested in are methods that:

- Are flexible, in the sense that it's easy to incorporate additional features (for example, If I'd like to weight recommendations by title genre, query time of day, etc).
- Item-to-Item. The system I have in mind will be used to find items similar to other items, agnostic of users.
- Space efficient. I do not want to keep track of a different model for each level of granularity of the query input, but rather *reuse* components of the model, and incorporate new components when optional information is provided.

---

If you know of any methods, papers or applications that you think could serve my purpose, please link it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with using matrix factorization for the recommender problem, then you can incorporate other information by simply augmenting your matrix, i.e., instead of factoring the matrix

Users x titles

you would factor the matrix

Users x (titles + meta data)

where the first set of columns would all correspond to ranked movies and the second set would represent other meta data about each user.

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer an item-to-item flavor of recommender - as new users come on to my platform frequently, and I'm more interested in finding items that are _similar_ to other items.